# Interpolation - Numba

Tags: python, interpolation, numba

I'm using  interpolate.interp1d from Scipy to interpolate a 1d array in Python3. I would like to use it with numba, but scipy and this function are not supported. Is there an interpolation function supported by numba, or a way to do an interpolation with numba?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `numpy`'s interpolation function for 1d arrays. You have a list of the numpy functions supported by numba [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html):

> numpy.interp() (only the 3 first arguments; requires NumPy >= 1.10)

If you can't get it to work, it's prbably the version of numba. Here's a working example using the same example as in [`np.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def interp_nb(x_vals, x, y):
    return np.interp(xvals, x, y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
xvals = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)

y_interp = interp_nb(xvals, x, y)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xvals, y_interp, '-x')
```

[image]

```
numba.__version__
# '0.43.1'

np.__version__
# '1.18.1'
```

Comment: My NumPy version is 1.15.4, I'm using Python 3.7 and the version of numba I have is 0.41.0. I still have this error: Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.interp' or unsupported use of the function.

Comment: Is there a performance advantage in just wrapping the interp function?

Comment: No, none. Interp is already vectorized, so as per formant as it'll get. My guess is that its just part of a calculation which contains more loopy code @jan this here is just to illustrate that it is supported